# Regex non-consecutive chars

Tags: regex

Currently I have:

```
[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]
```

This matches any string that contains letters, numbers, and certain special chars (`._%+-`)

How can I change this so that it won't match a string that contains the special chars consecutively?

For example, I want it to match:
`foo.bar+test` and `foo.+bar` and `+foo.`

But not:
`foo..bar+test` or `foo.bar++test` or `foo.bar++`

Comment: Additional cases: should `+foo.bar`, `foo.+bar`, or `foo.bar+` match?

Comment: @Ben: clearly not the second one.

Comment: @SilentGhost — His examples only show two of the *same* special character consecutively, so I thought it worth asking.  ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your tool/language supports look aheads, try:

```
^(?!.*([._%+-])\1)[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+$
```

Comment: +1 for a working answer that only has the one forward assertion (rather than mine which loops for each special character)...

Answer (score 6):

```
^(?:[0-9A-Za-z]+|([._%+-])(?!\1))+$
```

Broken down:

- `(?:` … `)+` — one or more of **either**:

  - `[0-9A-Za-z]+` — one or more alphanumeric characters **or**
  - `([._%+-])` — any allowed non-alphanumeric

    - `(?!\1)` — which isn't followed by the exact same character

Allows:

- `foo`
- `foo.+bar`
- `-700.bar+baz`

Disallows:

- `foo..bar`
- `foo.+bar--baz`

It works by capturing the matched non-alphanumeric characters into the first backreference (`\1`) each time the outer, not capturing group is matched and using a negative look-ahead (`(?!` … `)`) to make sure the same character doesn't appear twice in a row.  Be aware that not all regex flavors support negative look-ahead!

Comment: `foo.+bar` appears to be valid (see bjacobs' comment under Gumbo's answer)

Comment: @Bart — Hmm… then I think I'll wait for more clarification before I take another stab at it.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
^(?!.*[._%+-]{2})[\w.%+-]+$
```

If only the same character cannot be repeated then use:

```
^(?!.*([._%+-])\1)[\w.%+-]+$
```

Comment: That does not match `foo.+bar` which appears to be valid (see bjacobs' comment under Gumbo's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP's PCRE, you can do this:

```
/^([A-Za-z0-9]|([._%+-])(?!\2))*$/
```

The `\2` is the back-reference that's required to detect a duplicate usage of the same symbol.  I'm not sure it's possible to do this without a forward assertion and a back-reference, so there is my working regex tested against:

```
'foo'         => true,
'bar.baz'     => true,
'bar.biz.buz' => true,
'bar.+bar'    => true,
'bar..bar'    => false,
'biz.baz..'   => false,
'..++..'      => false,
'.faf.'       => true,
```