# Regex help with specific char

Tags: regex

I recently got an answer to a question:
[Consecutive Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739395/regex-non-consecutive-chars)

But now I want to match only if there is an @ symbol in there.

The original regex is:

```
(?!.*([._%+-])\1)[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+
```

So I tried:

```
(?!.*([._%+-])\1)[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@(?!.*([._%+-])\1)[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+
```

But this doesn't allow any of my special chars to follow the @ symbol.

For instance, the above matches `+foo.bar+-test+@m` but not `+foo.bar+-test+@m+`

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?!.*([._%+-])\1)(?=.*@)[\w.%+@-]+$
```

Comment: Here's a tutorial on the (highly useful, IMHO) lookaround assertions. The `(?=.*@)` above is an example. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0):

You have reused backreference `\1`, therefore it stops you from matching the "special" char again. You don't need to repeat the lookahead assertion at all. Try

```
(?!.*([._%+-])\1)[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+
```